# Путь к картинке в MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, изображения, picturebox

При передачи строки расположения картинки убираются слеши (`\`);

Пример:

Передаю строку: `"D:\Projects\cgi-bin\imgabills-120x120.jpg"`

В итоге в БД: `D:Projectscgi-binimgabills-120x120.jpg`

Почему так получается?

Comment: И причем тут C#?

Comment: @rdom, Именно в С# у меня такое происходить. Об других языках не знаю.

Comment: Вставлять такие строки через какой-нибудь клиент для MySQL пробовали?

Comment: @rdom, Да, тоже удаляет

Comment: Это ограничение самого MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limits-windows.html, C# тут ни при чём.

Comment: @rdom, понял. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это ограничение MySQL для платформы Windows ([документация](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limits-windows.html))

Вам необходимо заменить `\` на `/` или `\\`.